# Use a symbolic link to create a new symbolic link

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have 2 directories (FOO, LALA). I create a symbolic link in one of them like this

```
ln -s /etc/apache2 FOO/apache2
```

Afterwards I want to create another symlink, pointing to the same directory, but not using the initial directory but the symlink created. So I try

```
ln -s FOO/apache2 LALA/apache2
```

The problem is that the second link is invalid.

```
ls FOO/apache2
```

The above works and lists files in /etc/apache2

```
ls LALA/apache2
```

But this one doesn't. It just lists the link itself.
If I add a slash at the end of each ls

```
ls FOO/apache2/
```

Works as well.

```
ls LALA/apache2/
```

I get *ls: cannot access LALA/apache2/: No such file or directory/*

---

If instead of

```
ln -s FOO/apache2 LALA/apache2
```

I do

```
cd LALA ; ln -s ../FOO/apache2 apache2
```

Then the symlink is valid

Any idea what's the difference?

---

Initial question from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656666/use-a-symbolic-link-to-create-a-new-symbolic-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that relative symlinks are resolved at *access time*, not creation time.

---

In your first example, if the link's name is `/somedir/LALA/apache2` and its target is `FOO/apache2`, it will be resolved to `/somedir/LALA/FOO/apache2` when accessing it.

```
link name:                link target:    absolute target:
"/somedir/LALA/apache2" + "FOO/apache2" = "/somedir/LALA/FOO/apache2"
```

In the second example, the link's name is same – `/somedir/LALA/apache2` – but its target, `../FOO/apache2`, is now resolved as:

```
link name:                link target:       absolute target:
"/somedir/LALA/apache2" + "../FOO/apache2" = "/somedir/LALA/../FOO/apache2"
                                           → "/somedir/FOO/apache2"
```

---

This means that you **must always give "`../FOO/apache2`" as the target** to `ln -s` when creating the second link, *regardless* of what directory you are currently in.

Note: In the latest version of *coreutils*, the `ln` command has a new option `-r`/`--relative`, which does the job for you. For example, `ln -r -s FOO/apache2 LALA/apache2` would work correctly.

For older versions, you could hack something with `realpath --strip --relative-to`...
I wrote [`sym`](https://raw.github.com/grawity/code/master/misc/sym) for my own use.

Comment: Great. That was the problem... Really strange if you ask me. I'll probably end up using readlink in the first symlink and create the second one with the result from readlink as the target.

Comment: @GeorgeKastrinis: Maybe [this script](https://raw.github.com/grawity/code/master/misc/sym) will be useful.